# How to check if a map contains a key in Go?

Tags: dictionary, go, go-map

I know I can iterate over a map `m` with

```
for k, v := range m { ... }
```

and look for a key, but is there a more efficient way of testing for a key's existence in a map?

Comment: Here's where to find the answer in the linked spec: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Index_expressions

Answer (score 2607, accepted):

Here's how you check if a map contains a key.

```golang
val, ok := myMap["foo"]
// If the key exists
if ok {
    // Do something
}
```

This initializes two variables. `val` is the value of "foo" from the map if it exists, or a "zero value" if it doesn't (in this case the empty string). `ok` is a `bool` that will be set to `true` if the key existed.

If you want, you can shorten this to a one-liner.

```golang
if val, ok := myMap["foo"]; ok {
    //do something here
}
```

Go allows you to put an initializing statement before the condition (notice the semicolon) in the if statement. The consequence of this is that the scope of`val` and `ok` will be limited to the body of the if statement, which is helpful if you only need to access them there.

Comment: What would happen if one line above `if val,ok ...` a val was declared: `var val string = ""`?

Comment: @Kiril `var val string = ""` will remain the same, `val, ok :=` creates a new local variable with the same name that's only visibile in that block.

Comment: @Mheni, I know I'm a bit late here, but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29677670/what-is-the-big-o-performance-of-maps-in-golang) discusses the lookup complexity in go. Most of the time the [amortized complexity](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3110/2011sp/Lectures/lec20-amortized/amortized.htm) is O(1) but it's worth reading the answers on that question.

Comment: Notice that if you have an 'AND' condition it must go after the key exists. Is there any way around this?

Comment: @PrashantSaraswat nope, if you want the AND to come before, you'll need to break up the if statement.

Comment: how would you do the reverse? If the key was NOT in the map?

Comment: @alex `if _, ok := dict["foo"]; !ok {}`

Comment: If you only want to check the existence of a certain key, you can use the blank identifier (_) in place of val. Like so:

`if _, ok := dict["foo"]; ok {
    //do something here
}`

Comment: Is is possible to check if a key exists in two different maps within the same if statement?

Comment: It's interesting that val will also be in the scope of the else clause (if present)

Comment: Kinda confusing that `(x, err)` and `(x, ok)` are both used by Go.

Answer (score 204):

In addition to [The Go Programming Language Specification](http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html), you should read [Effective Go](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html). In the section on [maps](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#maps), they say, amongst other things:

> An attempt to fetch a map value with a key that is not present in the
>   map will return the zero value for the type of the entries in the map.
>   For instance, if the map contains integers, looking up a non-existent
>   key will return 0. A set can be implemented as a map with value type
>   bool. Set the map entry to true to put the value in the set, and then
>   test it by simple indexing.
>
> ```
> attended := map[string]bool{
>     "Ann": true,
>     "Joe": true,
>     ...
> }
>
> if attended[person] { // will be false if person is not in the map
>     fmt.Println(person, "was at the meeting")
> }
> ```
>
> Sometimes you need to distinguish a missing entry from a zero value.
>   Is there an entry for "UTC" or is that 0 because it's not in the map
>   at all? You can discriminate with a form of multiple assignment.
>
> ```
> var seconds int
> var ok bool
> seconds, ok = timeZone[tz]
> ```
>
> For obvious reasons this is called the “comma ok” idiom. In this
>   example, if tz is present, seconds will be set appropriately and ok
>   will be true; if not, seconds will be set to zero and ok will be
>   false. Here's a function that puts it together with a nice error
>   report:
>
> ```
> func offset(tz string) int {
>     if seconds, ok := timeZone[tz]; ok {
>         return seconds
>     }
>     log.Println("unknown time zone:", tz)
>     return 0
> }
> ```
>
> To test for presence in the map without worrying about the actual
>   value, you can use the blank identifier (_) in place of the usual
>   variable for the value.
>
> ```
> _, present := timeZone[tz]
> ```

Comment: https://go.dev/play/p/X4liolwTsVL didn't work

Comment: @ar-siddiqui: peterSO's idea was that you initialized "person" before using it, but here you go, a full working example: https://go.dev/play/p/_51LQmwicuO

Comment: This works for primitives but as soon as you have map[somePrimitive]someStruct{} it won't work, you would need to go further to have a boolean statement for go to work with, see example: https://go.dev/play/p/LVvS0ojOJpI

Answer (score 114):

Searched on the [go-nuts email list](http://groups.google.com/group/golang-nuts) and found a solution posted by Peter Froehlich on 11/15/2009.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
        dict := map[string]int {"foo" : 1, "bar" : 2}
        value, ok := dict["baz"]
        if ok {
                fmt.Println("value: ", value)
        } else {
                fmt.Println("key not found")
        }
}
```

Or, more compactly,

```
if value, ok := dict["baz"]; ok {
    fmt.Println("value: ", value)
} else {
    fmt.Println("key not found")
}
```

Note, using this form of the `if` statement, the `value` and `ok` variables are only visible inside the `if` conditions.

Comment: If you really are just interested in whether the key exists or not, and don't care about the value, you can use `_, ok := dict["baz"]; ok`. The `_` part throws the value away instead of creating a temporary variable.

Answer (score 55):

## Short Answer

```
_, exists := timeZone[tz]    // Just checks for key existence
val, exists := timeZone[tz]  // Checks for key existence and retrieves the value
```

## Example

Here's an [example at the Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/1yncAI-Bpk).

## Longer Answer

Per the [Maps](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#maps) section of [Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#maps):

> An attempt to fetch a map value with a key that is not present in the map will return the zero value for the type of the entries in the map. For instance, if the map contains integers, looking up a non-existent key will return 0.
>
> Sometimes you need to distinguish a missing entry from a zero value. Is there an entry for "UTC" or is that the empty string because it's not in the map at all? You can discriminate with a form of multiple assignment.
>
> ```
> var seconds int
> var ok bool
> seconds, ok = timeZone[tz]
> ```
>
> For obvious reasons this is called the “comma ok” idiom. In this example, if tz is present, seconds will be set appropriately and ok will be true; if not, seconds will be set to zero and ok will be false. Here's a function that puts it together with a nice error report:
>
> ```
> func offset(tz string) int {
>     if seconds, ok := timeZone[tz]; ok {
>         return seconds
>     }
>     log.Println("unknown time zone:", tz)
>     return 0
> }
> ```
>
> To test for presence in the map without worrying about the actual value, you can use the blank identifier (_) in place of the usual variable for the value.
>
> ```
> _, present := timeZone[tz]
> ```

Answer (score 41):

Have a look at this snippet of code

```golang
nameMap := make(map[string]int)
nameMap["river"] = 33
v ,exist := nameMap["river"]
if exist {
    fmt.Println("exist ",v)
}
```

Answer (score 31):

```golang
var d map[string]string
value, ok := d["key"]
if ok {
    fmt.Println("Key Present ", value)
} else {
    fmt.Println(" Key Not Present ")
}
```

Answer (score 28):

As noted by other answers, the general solution is to use an [index expression](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Index_expressions) in an [assignment](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignments) of the special form:

```
v, ok = a[x]
v, ok := a[x]
var v, ok = a[x]
var v, ok T = a[x]
```

This is nice and clean. It has some restrictions though: it must be an assignment of special form. Right-hand side expression must be the map index expression only, and the left-hand expression list must contain exactly 2 operands, first to which the value type is assignable, and a second to which a `bool` value is assignable. The first value of the result of this special form will be the value associated with the key, and the second value will tell if there is actually an entry in the map with the given key (if the key exists in the map). The left-hand side expression list may also contain the [blank identifier](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Blank_identifier) if one of the results is not needed.

It's important to know that if the indexed map value is `nil` or does not contain the key, the index expression evaluates to the [zero value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value) of the value type of the map. So for example:

```
m := map[int]string{}
s := m[1] // s will be the empty string ""
var m2 map[int]float64 // m2 is nil!
f := m2[2] // f will be 0.0

fmt.Printf("%q %f", s, f) // Prints: "" 0.000000
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/X6u0Oyb7bE).

So if we know that we don't use the zero value in our map, we can take advantage of this.

For example if the value type is `string`, and we know we never store entries in the map where the value is the empty string (zero value for the `string` type), we can also test if the key is in the map by comparing the non-special form of the (result of the) index expression to the zero value:

```
m := map[int]string{
    0: "zero",
    1: "one",
}

fmt.Printf("Key 0 exists: %t\nKey 1 exists: %t\nKey 2 exists: %t",
    m[0] != "", m[1] != "", m[2] != "")
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/xmAvEHa7t6)):

```
Key 0 exists: true
Key 1 exists: true
Key 2 exists: false
```

In practice there are many cases where we don't store the zero-value value in the map, so this can be used quite often. For example interfaces and function types have a zero value `nil`, which we often don't store in maps. So testing if a key is in the map can be achieved by comparing it to `nil`.

Using this "technique" has another advantage too: you can check existence of multiple keys in a compact way (you can't do that with the special "comma ok" form). More about this: [Check if key exists in multiple maps in one condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41978101/check-if-key-exists-in-multiple-maps-in-one-condition/41978277#41978277)

Getting the zero value of the value type when indexing with a non-existing key also allows us to use maps with `bool` values conveniently as *sets*. For example:

```
set := map[string]bool{
    "one": true,
    "two": true,
}

fmt.Println("Contains 'one':", set["one"])

if set["two"] {
    fmt.Println("'two' is in the set")
}
if !set["three"] {
    fmt.Println("'three' is not in the set")
}
```

It outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Lw94Z8zYyEl)):

```
Contains 'one': true
'two' is in the set
'three' is not in the set
```

See related: [How can I create an array that contains unique strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33207197/how-can-i-create-an-array-that-contains-unique-strings/33207265#33207265)

Comment: what is `T` in `var v, ok T = a[x]`? isn't `ok` must be bool?

Comment: @Kokizzu That's the general form of the variable declaration. At first we might think it would only work (compile) if the map would be of type `map[bool]bool` and `T` is `bool`, but it also works if map is of type `map[interface{}]bool` and `T` is `interface{}`; moreover it also works with custom types having `bool` as underlying type, see all on the [**Go Playground**](https://play.golang.org/p/lqJa8BZv49). So since that form is valid with multiple types substituted for `T`, that's why the general `T` is used. Type of `ok` can be anything to which an **untyped `bool`** can be assigned.

Answer (score 6):

```
    var empty struct{}
    var ok bool
    var m map[string]struct{}
    m = make(map[string]struct{})
    m["somestring"] = empty


    _, ok = m["somestring"]
    fmt.Println("somestring exists?", ok) 
    _, ok = m["not"]
    fmt.Println("not exists?", ok)
```

Then, go run maps.go 
somestring exists? true
not exists? false

Comment: Gets rid of the need for int

Comment: Thanks for the contribution, but I think the current answers cover the question well. From what you're saying here your answer would more fit a _Best way of implementing set in Go_ type of question.

Comment: ```_, ok = m["somestring"]``` should be ```=_, ok := m["somestring"]```

Answer (score 5):

It is mentioned under ["Index expressions"](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Index_expressions).

> An index expression on a map a of type map[K]V used in an assignment
>   or initialization of the special form
>
> ```
> v, ok = a[x] 
> v, ok := a[x] 
> var v, ok = a[x]
> ```
>
> yields an additional untyped boolean value. The value of ok is true if
>   the key x is present in the map, and false otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

A two value assignment can be used for this purpose. Please check my sample program below

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    //creating a map with 3 key-value pairs
    sampleMap := map[string]int{"key1": 100, "key2": 500, "key3": 999}
    //A two value assignment can be used to check existence of a key.
    value, isKeyPresent := sampleMap["key2"]
    //isKeyPresent will be true if key present in sampleMap
    if isKeyPresent {
        //key exist
        fmt.Println("key present, value =  ", value)
    } else {
        //key does not exist
        fmt.Println("key does not exist")
    }
}
```

Answer (score -5):

Example usage: Looping through a slice, for pairMap checking if key exists.
It an algorithm to find all pairs that adds to a specific sum.

```
func findPairs(slice1 []int, sum int) {
    pairMap := make(map[int]int)
    for i, v := range slice1 {
        if valuei, ok := pairMap[v]; ok {
            fmt.Println("Pair Found", i, valuei)
        } else {
            pairMap[sum-v] = i
        }
    }
}
```