# How to check if a slice has a given index in Go?

Tags: go, slice

We can easily do that with maps:

```
item, ok := myMap["index"]
```

But not with slices:

```
item, ok := mySlice[3] // panic!
```

Surprised this wasn't asked before. Maybe I'm on the wrong mental model with Go slices?

Comment: why so many downvoters? You can't make any question anymore without somebody getting unhappy here.

Comment: I can't see why either. It's not unreasonable to think that maps and slices would work the same, just like std::map and std::vector have a similar interface in C++.

Comment: I (wrongly) assumed Go slices were basically maps with consecutive int keys. A quick look on the syntax can make you adopt this mental model, BTW.

Still don't get why the desire to downvote a question because of that, though. Makes me wonder if Go community is being invaded by passive aggressive CI students or something LOL

Comment: "shows little effort" this is quite relative from person to person. If you follow this criteria you would need to downvote 80% of [go] questions because it's on the go tour or docs or language specs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050391/how-to-test-key-existence-in-a-map

Comment: true (unfortunately, many of them do). That also may have recently changed and wasn't well documented in 2010, because the first release candidate didn't come out until 2011.

Comment: I couldn't find any information explaining explicitly that you need to check length of a slice anywere. IMMO it would be really good to have a more consistent interface between maps and slices. Anyway, thanks to stack overflow, the question is answered.

Comment: @marioAlmada It's even worse, if you create a program that uses variable amount of arguments (for example -? or -help or -help debug), you must check the length of the arguments every time.

Comment: @marcioAlmada please stop guessing. APL syntax and semantics do not work in Java, C++ semantics don't apply to to Lisp and whatever-other-language is not a suitable reference to Go. I really can recommend the Go Tour, Effective Go and the language reference. E.g. out of rangle slice access is clearly described in http://golang.org/ref/spec#Index_expressions .

Comment: @Dippo totally agree, it's the first thing I really dislike in Go, for now.

Comment: @Volker no way, "guess" is half the fun of discovery, specially when you guess right.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

There is no sparse slices in Go, so you could simply check the length:

```
if len(mySlice) > 3 {
    // ...
}
```

If the length is greater than 3, you know that the index 3 and all those before that exist.

Comment: So to know if I can get `mySlice[3]` the slice needs to have index 4? That's weird. What if index 3 is the last one?

Comment: Indexes start at 0, so you need a length of 4 if you want something at index 3.

Comment: All right, it seems I understood Go slices wrong. I thought it was basically a map with consecutive int keys. A quick look on the syntax can make you adopt this mental model :)

Comment: @marcioAlmada sounds like you're coming from javascript / php.

Comment: @OneOfOne Now you're the one making wrong assumptions :) I work with C++, Lua, Red, Python, PHP, Javascript and a bit of Ruby (don't like ruby).

Comment: @marcioAlmada you did mention php and javascript ;) hence the whole array-as-object thing

Comment: Not only with PHP and JS, Lua and C++ baggage can make you think like this too. Anyway, it's a shame Go slices have no better way to check for an index, it totally breaks code consistency with this `if len(thing) > i { ... }` idea opposed to `item, ok := thing[i]`.

Comment: yeah golang clearly wasn't developed with the programmer in mind