# How can I create an array that contains unique strings?

Tags: arrays, string, go, slice

I want to create an array that contains unique strings. How can I do that?

```
var paths = make([]string, 0)

func main() {
    // Members are added dynamically
    paths = append(paths, "aaa")
    paths = append(paths, "bbb")
    paths = append(paths, "bbb")
    paths = append(paths, "ccc")

    // convert ["aaa", "bbb", "bbb", "ccc"] -> ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"] 
    // or can I use some class that disallow the same string automaticaly?
}
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If you want a collection of unique elements, that is the [Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(abstract_data_type)) data type. Go does not have a builtin set data type, but you can use a map to act as a set: keys in a map must be unique.

For a "nice" set, use a map with `bool` value type (with `true` values) and exploit the [zero value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value). For a set with the smallest memory footprint, use a map with `struct{}` value type as values of `struct{}` type occupy no memory; and use the comma-ok idiom to tell if a value is in the set / map.

Here's how the "nice" version of set looks like. Instead of a slice add your elements to a `map[string]bool` as the key with a `true` as the value:

```
m := make(map[string]bool)

m["aaa"] = true
m["bbb"] = true
m["bbb"] = true
m["ccc"] = true
```

To check if an element is already in the collection (map), you can simply use an [index expression](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Index_expressions):

```
exists := m["somevalue"]
```

This exploits the [zero value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value), that is if the map does not yet contain an element, the zero value of the value type is returned which is `false` in case of `bool` type, properly indicating that the element is not in the collection.

Elements in a map have no fixed order. If you need to keep the order (e.g. insertion order), then use a slice (to remember the order) and a map (to tell if an element to be added is new). This is easiest with a helper `add()` function:

```
var m = make(map[string]bool)
var a = []string{}

func main() {
    add("aaa")
    add("bbb")
    add("bbb")
    add("ccc")
}

func add(s string) {
    if m[s] {
        return // Already in the map
    }
    a = append(a, s)
    m[s] = true
}
```

Comment: icza, thank you for your answer and grammar check!
Hmm, I see, I understood that I need to treat Set data type myself in Go.
Your source code is clear. It was easy to understand. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func UniqueSliceElements[T comparable](inputSlice []T) []T {
    uniqueSlice := make([]T, 0, len(inputSlice))
    seen := make(map[T]bool, len(inputSlice))
    for _, element := range inputSlice {
        if !seen[element] {
            uniqueSlice = append(uniqueSlice, element)
            seen[element] = true
        }
    }
    return uniqueSlice
}

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("Strings: %v\n", UniqueSliceElements([]string{"a", "a", "b", "b", "x"}))
    fmt.Printf("Ints: %v\n", UniqueSliceElements([]int{1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3}))
}
```

Playground: https://go.dev/play/p/Zm-h-z888zm