# Remove duplicates from map of slices

Tags: dictionary, go, slice

I have a map of slices that I need to remove duplicates from. I think I'm close to the solution but I'm missing something that I can't quite figure out.

Expected output: `map[key1:[1 2 3] key2:[1 2 3]]`

Actual output: `map[key2:[1 2 3]]`

```golang
    package main

    import "fmt"

    func main() {
        x := make(map[string][]string)
        keys := make(map[string]bool)
        result := make(map[string][]string)

        x["key1"] = append(x["key1"], "1")
        x["key1"] = append(x["key1"], "1")
        x["key1"] = append(x["key1"], "2")
        x["key1"] = append(x["key1"], "3")
        x["key1"] = append(x["key1"], "3")
        x["key2"] = append(x["key2"], "1")
        x["key2"] = append(x["key2"], "2")
        x["key2"] = append(x["key2"], "2")
        x["key2"] = append(x["key2"], "3")

        fmt.Println(x)

        for k, e := range x{
            for _, v := range e {
                if _, val := keys[v]; !val {
                    keys[v] = true
                    result[k] = append(result[k], v)
                }
            }
        }
        fmt.Println(result)
    }
```

Example on the playground here: [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/HbycgyC5SI6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want all slices to be handled separately. E.g. you want to remove duplicates from the slice denoted by `x["key1"]`, and you want to remove duplicates from the slice denoted by `x["key2"]`. Which means you should "reset" `keys` when a new slice is being processed, yet you only initialize it once.

As a consequence, if (by any chance) you process `x["key1"]` first, and then you proceed to `x["key2"]`, since `x["key1"]` contains all the elements that  `x["key2"]` does, no new elements will be found, so `"key2"` will be left out from the result entirely.

Simply initialize `keys` before each slice, inside the loop:

```
for k, e := range x {
    keys := make(map[string]bool)
    for _, v := range e {
        if _, val := keys[v]; !val {
            keys[v] = true
            result[k] = append(result[k], v)
        }
    }
}
```

With this, the output will be (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/b8zRoPT7s4t)):

```
map[key1:[1 1 2 3 3] key2:[1 2 2 3]]
map[key1:[1 2 3] key2:[1 2 3]]
```

Also note that you can use a [composite literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals) to create your initial map in a compact way like this:

```
x := map[string][]string{
    "key1": {"1", "1", "2", "3", "3"},
    "key2": {"1", "2", "2", "3"},
}
```

And since you use `bool` in your `keys` map, you may simply check for existing elements like this (because indexing a map with a key that is not in it results in the zero value of the map's value type, which for `bool` is `false`, properly telling the element is not in the map):

```
if !keys[v] {
    keys[v] = true
    result[k] = append(result[k], v)
}
```

Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/sUeYdywKGkY).

You can read more about this here: [How to check if a map contains a key in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050391/how-to-check-if-a-map-contains-a-key-in-go/43272888#43272888); and [How can I create an array that contains unique strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33207197/how-can-i-create-an-array-that-contains-unique-strings/33207265#33207265)

Comment: Yes, that makes perfect sense. Thank you for pointing that out. I was staring at it too long to see it :)