# Avoiding need for redundant check to map given zero value of string?

Tags: dictionary, go

We have a `map[string]string`, I assume that means the zero value of a string retrieved from the map is `""`

So doesn't that mean that this:

```
var userId, ok = params["user_id"];

if !ok || userId == "" {
    return 422, "Missing user_id in request"
}
```

is the same logic as this:

```
var userId = params["user_id"];

if  userId == "" {
    return 422, "Missing user_id in request"
}
```

just making sure my understanding is correct.

Comment: "is the same logic as this". No, these are not equivalent if  `params` contains an empty string "". Otherwise yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not the same if you intend to store the zero value of the value type.

See this example:

```
m := map[string]string{
    "empty": "",
}

if v, ok := m["empty"]; ok {
    fmt.Printf("'empty' is present: %q\n", v)
} else {
    fmt.Println("'empty' is not present")
}
if v, ok := m["missing"]; ok {
    fmt.Printf("'missing' is present: %q\n", v)
} else {
    fmt.Printf("'missing' is not present")
}
```

It outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/d4oXescAD1l)):

```
'empty' is present: ""
'missing' is not present
```

It's true that if you never store the zero value in the map, you may simply use `if m[value] == zeroValue {}`. This is detailed here: [How to check if a map contains a key in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050391/how-to-check-if-a-map-contains-a-key-in-go/43272888#43272888)

This "property" of maps can be exploited to create sets elegantly. See [How can I create an array that contains unique strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33207197/how-can-i-create-an-array-that-contains-unique-strings/33207265#33207265)

And using this "technique" has another advantage too: you can check existence of multiple keys in a compact way (you can't do that with the special "comma ok" form). More about this: [Check if key exists in multiple maps in one condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41978101/check-if-key-exists-in-multiple-maps-in-one-condition/41978277#41978277)