# How to check for three different struct keys in the golang map?

Tags: dictionary, go

I have a below method where I create three different struct object to check as a key in my `name` map. If I can find the value, I return back otherwise I return empty string and status.

```
func (r *clientRepo) GetName(id int64, name map[models.LocaleInfo]string, clientId int32, code models.Locale) (string, bool) {
    localeInfo := models.LocaleInfo{
        Locale:  code,
        GroupID: int(clientId),
    }

    localeInfoUS := models.LocaleInfo{
        Locale:  "US",
        GroupID: int(clientId),
    }

    localeInfoGB := models.LocaleInfo{
        Locale:  "GB",
        GroupID: int(clientId),
    }

    value := ""
    ok := false
    if value, ok = name[localeInfo]; !ok {
        if value, ok = name[localeInfoUS]; !ok {
            if value, ok := name[localeInfoGB]; !ok {
                errs.Newf("Unable to find locale for ProductId: %d", id)
                return value, ok
            }
        }
    }
    
    return value, ok
}
```

Is there any way to improve above code where I don't have to keep separate line for each US and GB locale info. My if block also looks very nested and I think that can be improved a lot as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The special "comma-ok" form can only be used in an assignment, so you can't make it more compact.

What you may do is write a utility function which uses a for loop to check any number of keys.

Using Go 1.18 generics, you can make it work with any map type:

```
func findKeys[K comparable, V any](m map[K]V, keys ...K) (v V, ok bool) {
    for _, key := range keys {
        if v, ok = m[key]; ok {
            return
        }
    }
    return
}
```

Testing it:

```
m := map[int]string{
    1: "one",
    2: "two",
    3: "three",
    4: "four",
}

fmt.Println(findKeys(m, 5, 6, 4))
fmt.Println(findKeys(m, 1, 2, 6))
fmt.Println(findKeys(m, 6, 8))
```

Which outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/DxqklVbeFQ0)):

```
four true
one true
 false
```

Note: if you're using a Go prior to Go 1.18, simply use a non-generic version of `findKeys()`:

```
func findKeys(m map[models.LocaleInfo]string, keys ...models.LocaleInfo) (v string, ok bool) {
    for _, key := range keys {
        if v, ok = m[key]; ok {
            return
        }
    }
    return
}
```

You could use this `findKeys()` like this:

```
value, ok := findKeys(name, localeInfo, localeInfoUS, localeInfoGB)
if !ok {
    errs.Newf("Unable to find locale for ProductId: %d", id)
}
return value, ok
```

Also note that if you're using a non-generic version, since it will be restricted to your map type anyway, you can move more code into it: it can handle the key creation, so you only have to pass the `string` locale values (and the `clientId`):

```
func findKeys(names map[models.LocaleInfo]string, clientId int, locales ...string) (v string, ok bool) {
    key := models.LocaleInfo{GroupID: clientId}
    for _, locale := range locales {
        key.Locale = locale
        if v, ok = names[key]; ok {
            return
        }
    }
    return
}
```

Calling it is like:

```
value, ok := findKeys(names, int(clientId), code, "US", "GB")
```

See related question: [Check if key exists in multiple maps in one condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41978101/check-if-key-exists-in-multiple-maps-in-one-condition/41978277#41978277)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I am still working with 1.17. How will I accomplish this better using 1.17? In my case, map is same but different keys.

Comment: @rosed Then simply use a non-generic version of `findKeys()`, see edited answer.

Comment: Got it. That make sense. So I will still have three different `localeInfo` object as it is just that if block is improved. Right?

Comment: @rosed You can have as many keys as you want. Also note that if you're using a non-generic version which is restricted to your map type anyway, you can move the key creation to the utility function, so using it will be a lot easier. See edited answer.

Comment: Quick question - `range locale {` this should be `locales` right? And also getting error at `key.Locale = locale` bcoz `key.Locale` is an object.

Comment: @rosed Yes, `locale` => `locales` was a typo, but please note in this version `locales` is a `string` slice, not an object slice! So `key.Locale = locale` is valid.