# Check if a value exists in a map in Golang

Tags: performance, dictionary, go

I am searching for an efficient way to check if a value exists in Golang. The way I know is using a for loop/ range. Is there a better way to do the same?

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: The question is confusing - you say you want to know if a map contains a *value*, but you compare to Java's `containsKey`, which checks if a map contains a *key*. Which are you looking for?

Comment: If you're looking for how to tell that a key exists, the answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050391/how-to-check-if-a-map-contains-a-key-in-go

Comment: @Adrian .. Apologies for the confusion. I have edited the question.

Comment: @TimothyJones  I have the value and check if the value exists in the map and if yes, then extract the key

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no built in way to find out if a map contains a particular value. If you need this behaviour to be efficient, consider using an additional data structure to support it.

Note that although Java's `Map` provides [`containsValue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#containsValue-java.lang.Object-), the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#containsValue-java.lang.Object-) says:

> This operation will probably require time linear in the map size for most implementations of the Map interface.

So, if you need an efficient implementation for a Java Map, you also need to provide one.

What "an efficient implementation" means changes based on what kind of data you're mapping. For example, if values are always unique, then maintaining a `map[value]key` is enough). If they're not, then something more principled is needed.

Comment: If they are not unique, a `map[value][]key` might work, though it's more effort to maintain.

Answer (score 8):

When you index a map in Go you get two return values; the second one (which is optional) is a boolean that indicates if the key exists.

If the key doesn’t exist, the first value will be the default zero value.

Use second return value directly in an if statement.

```
m := map[string]float64{"pi": 3.14}
if v, found := m["pi"]; found {
    fmt.Println(v)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have rather big map and want to optimize value checking then add one more map nearly. Like`map[valueType]int`.  Then:

```
for k, v := range m {
    values[v]++
}
```