# Determining if delete actually removed an existing key in a map

Tags: go

I have a `map` called `nearby`

```
func Delete(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    params := mux.Vars(r)
    delete(nearby, params["id"])
}
```

I want to find out if the delete() call actually found a key to delete, I tried reading the return value:

```
func Delete(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    params := mux.Vars(r)
    result := delete(nearby, params["id"])
}
```

but the compiler didn't like that - how can I find out if a key/val was deleted?

Comment: Related: [How to check if a map contains a key in go?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2050391/1068283)

Comment: I see your `delete()` is part of an http request. It's actually not bad design-wise to keep it this way, as the request stays idempotent (ie multiple delete operations end up with the same result).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probe the map before deleting the value:

```
func Delete(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    params := mux.Vars(r)
    _, deleted := nearby[params["id"]]
    delete(nearby, params["id"])
    fmt.Println(deleted)
}
```

This snippet and the code in the question have a data race because HTTP handlers can be called concurrently.  Add a mutex to protect the map.

```
var (
    nearby = make(map[string]string)
    mu     sync.Mutex
)

func Delete(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    params := mux.Vars(r)
    mu.Lock()
    _, deleted := nearby[params["id"]]
    delete(nearby, params["id"])
    mu.Unlock()
    fmt.Println(deleted)
}
```

Comment: upvoted..why doesn't golang offer something builtin that can return whether `delete()` did anything? fml. why not another utility called `deletem()` or anything really

Comment: Even I'll go with this answer as you did mention that concurrent writes to a map aren't safe. There are probably several other places where you modify this map that should also be protected with this same mutex.

Comment: @MrCholo  See https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/5tfx7i/why_delete_doesnt_return_a_bool/ for discussion on delete return value.

Answer (score 3):

The Go builtin `delete()` doesn't return anything, so you can't tell whether it deleted anything.

But you *can* [check if the map contains the key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2050391/1068283) and `delete()` it if it is present.

```
if _, ok := nearby[params["id"]]; ok {
    delete(nearby, params["id"])
} else {
    // whatever
}
```

Comment: why do you need the `; ok {` part?

Comment: @MrCholo https://tour.golang.org/flowcontrol/6 Really, go take the tour, we're not kidding about this!

Comment: hmmm, well if the question doesn't already exist on SO then it's good to have a question like this for others to see